# Replacing face time video calls iOS4 - iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, ios4, video-streaming

I would like to change what the camera 'captures' to something else during a video call.
Lets say I have an image that I want to be seen on the other side instead of the video sent from the camera.
I want to 'hack' the camera on the iPhone - get control on the data being sent.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without jailbreaking and a lot of work inside MobilePhone.app

Start by running `class-dump-z` on `/Applications/MobilePhone.app/MobilePhone`